# Difference of two graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given two graphs $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ what exactly is the definition of $G_{1}-G_{2}$ used in the Diestel book? Most operations on graphs are clearly defined apart from this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the first paragarph on page $4$ of the Electronic Edition $2000$:

> If $U$ is any set of vertices (usually of $G$), we write $G-U$ for $G[V\setminus U]$. In other words, $G-U$ is obtained from $G$ by *deleting* all the vertices in $U\cap V$ and their incident edges. ... Instead of $G-V(G')$ we simply write $G-G'$.